# moving AnnotationBbox after intital draw in matplotlib in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to draw annotation images in a matplotlib plot, and be able to move them after plotting.

To that end, I started from the demo:
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html

with the notebook backend:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.offsetbox import (TextArea, DrawingArea, OffsetImage,
                                  AnnotationBbox)
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Define a 1st position to annotate (display it with a marker)
xy = (0.5, 0.7)
ax.plot(xy[0], xy[1], ".r")

# Annotate the 1st position with a text box ('Test 1')
offsetbox = TextArea("Test 1", minimumdescent=False)

ab = AnnotationBbox(offsetbox, xy,
                    xybox=(-20, 40),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords="offset points",
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
ax.add_artist(ab)

# Annotate the 1st position with another text box ('Test')
offsetbox = TextArea("Test", minimumdescent=False)

ab = AnnotationBbox(offsetbox, xy,
                    xybox=(1.02, xy[1]),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords=("axes fraction", "data"),
                    box_alignment=(0., 0.5),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
ax.add_artist(ab)

# Define a 2nd position to annotate (don't display with a marker this time)
xy = [0.3, 0.55]

# Annotate the 2nd position with a circle patch
da = DrawingArea(20, 20, 0, 0)
p = Circle((10, 10), 10)
da.add_artist(p)

ab = AnnotationBbox(da, xy,
                    xybox=(1.02, xy[1]),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords=("axes fraction", "data"),
                    box_alignment=(0., 0.5),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

ax.add_artist(ab)

# Annotate the 2nd position with an image (a generated array of pixels)
arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
im = OffsetImage(arr, zoom=2)
im.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(im, xy,
                    xybox=(-50., 50.),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords="offset points",
                    pad=0.3,
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))

ax.add_artist(ab)

# Annotate the 2nd position with another image (a Grace Hopper portrait)
with get_sample_data("grace_hopper.png") as file:
    arr_img = plt.imread(file, format='png')

imagebox = OffsetImage(arr_img, zoom=0.2)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, xy,
                    xybox=(120., -80.),
                    xycoords='data',
                    boxcoords="offset points",
                    pad=0.5,
                    arrowprops=dict(
                        arrowstyle="->",
                        connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=90,rad=3")
                    )

ax.add_artist(ab)

# Fix the display limits to see everything
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image: displayed image]

To test how to move stuff, I execute in the next cell:

```
rnd = fig.canvas.renderer
print(rnd)
print(im.get_window_extent(rnd))
print(im.get_window_extent(rnd).get_points())
print(ab.xybox)
ab.xybox = (130, -70)
im._offset = (135.46666666666667, 301.6355555555555)
im.set_zoom(.5)
ab.update_positions(rnd)
print(ab.xybox)
print(im.get_window_extent(rnd).get_points())
ab.draw(rnd)
im.draw(rnd)
fig.draw(rnd)
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

and what I see is that I do get a break in the plotted line, showing that the annotationbbox is shifted, but all its content isn't. (here the line has been plotted first (blue), then all the shifting has been executed, with another line plot (orange))
Any suggestions on how I can actually move the image of Grace Hopper are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I was wondering a similar thing (and the matplotlib documentation is lacking), so I hacked up this example, which appears to work.  The key thing seems to be using fig.canvas.draw() after every change.  Also, I'm using matplotlib version 3.1.3

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

def onpick(evt):
    x = (evt.xdata, evt.ydata)
    ab.xybox = x
    print(ab.xybox)
    fig.canvas.draw()

pix = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
x, y = np.meshgrid(pix, pix)
p = np.cos(2*np.pi*x)*np.sin(8*np.pi*y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

im = OffsetImage(p, zoom=1, cmap = 'gray')
ab = AnnotationBbox(im, (0.5, 0.5), xycoords='data', frameon=False)
ax.add_artist(ab)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```